# Spring utility method to convert class to generic bean name

Tags: java, spring

My sources have constant that is class name with lowered first letter.

Is there Spring utility method that convert class type to string with lowered first letter? This allows me safely refactor class name.

For example:

```
SpringXXX.defaultBeanNameYYY(MyCustomBeanFactoryProcessor.class)
```

should produce:

```
myCustomBeanFactoryProcessor
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, a mechanism that forms bean names is called `BeanNameGenerator` (depending on the type of the context, it may be the `AnnotationBeanNameGenerator` or the `DefaultBeanNameGenerator`). To generate a name, it requires a bean definition and a context where this definition is from:

```
new AnnotationBeanNameGenerator().generateBeanName(definition, context);
```

For instance, you might write this processing in a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` subclass where a `ConfigurableListableBeanFactory` instance is given:

```
class MyCustomBeanFactoryProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory) throws BeansException {
        String beanName = new AnnotationBeanNameGenerator()
                .generateBeanName(new AnnotatedGenericBeanDefinition(MyCustomBeanFactoryProcessor.class),
                                  (BeanDefinitionRegistry) factory);
    }
}
```

Finally, if we threw away the context and all checks that Spring does, we could just execute:

```
Introspector.decapitalize(MyCustomBeanFactoryProcessor.class.getSimpleName());
```

or

```
Introspector.decapitalize(ClassUtils.getShortName(MyCustomBeanFactoryProcessor.class));
```

Comment: Wow! `Introspector.decapitalize` is in standard Java.

Comment: @gavenkoa, if you make these conversions out of Spring, probably, it's better not to use a Spring-specific class, isn't it? otherwise, I'd recommend considering the method with the context and definitions.

Answer (score 5):

Using `getSimpleName` string as a hint  from **@shi** for search query I found one such implementation in `spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.java`:

```
/**
 * Return the short string name of a Java class in uncapitalized JavaBeans
 * property format. Strips the outer class name in case of an inner class.
 * @param clazz the class
 * @return the short name rendered in a standard JavaBeans property format
 * @see java.beans.Introspector#decapitalize(String)
 */
public static String getShortNameAsProperty(Class<?> clazz) {
    String shortName = getShortName(clazz);
    int dotIndex = shortName.lastIndexOf(PACKAGE_SEPARATOR);
    shortName = (dotIndex != -1 ? shortName.substring(dotIndex + 1) : shortName);
    return Introspector.decapitalize(shortName);
}
```

Usage:

```
@Test
public void my() {
    String str = org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getShortNameAsProperty(MyCustomBeanFactoryProcessor.class);
    Assert.assertEquals("myCustomBeanFactoryProcessor", str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write one yourself like this:

```
    public class BeanUtils {
        public static String firstToLowerCase(Class clazz) {
            String string = clazz.getSimpleName();
            String post = string.substring(1, string.length());
            String first = ("" + string.charAt(0)).toLowerCase();
            return first + post;
        }
    }
```

And call like this: `BeanUtils.firstToLowerCase(MyCustomBeanFactoryProcessor.class)`

Comment: I assume OP wants to achieve it by Spring's resources rather than writing it manually.